# How to access particular item in array using $index (angular)

Tags: angularjs

This seems like it should be so simple but my brain is exploding. This is what I am trying to achieve using angular, I have my shopping list

```
app.controller("Destroyer", function($scope) {
    $scope.shoppingList = [
      {name: 'Milk'},
      {name: 'Eggs'},
      {name: 'Bread'},
      {name: 'Cheese'},
      {name: 'Ham'}
    ];

});
```

In my template I want to access the the the 3rd item for example

```
{{ shoppingList.name[$index == 2] }}
```

How do I do this? Thanks

EDIT: Answer {{ shoppingList[2].name }}

Comment: {{ shoppingList.name[2] }} ?

Comment: you can use $index only on ng-repeat

Comment: {{ shoppingList[2].name }}

Comment: {{ shoppingList.name[2] }} - this doesn't work

Comment: omg Anthony, thank you! haha I feel like such a fool cause I realise now why you put it in that position.

Answer (score 1):

```
if you know the index you can give like this

{{shoppingList[2].name}}

or in ng-repeat 

<div ng-repeat="list in shoppingList " ng-show="$index==2">{{list.name}}</div>
```